# Reduce amount of CSS generated by a SASS function

Tags: css, sass

I'm very new to the (I guess) more advanced features of SASS. Referencing [this](https://medium.com/@dmitriy.borodiy/easy-color-theming-with-scss-bc38fd5734d1) article I've been able to create a SASS setup that lets me easily do dark mode theming! I'd like to reduce the amount of CSS it generates, however, and wanted to know if I've reached the limit of my knowledge or just what SASS/CSS is capable of.

I have this map of "themes":

```
$themes: (
  light: (
    primaryOne: #f0f,
    primaryTwo: #0ff
  ),
  dark: (
    primaryOne: #000,
    primaryTwo: #111
  )
);
```

I have these mixins/functions that were mostly lifted from the article:

```
@mixin themify($themes: $themes) {
  @each $theme, $map in $themes {
    $theme-map: () !global;
    @each $key, $submap in $map {
      $value: map-get(map-get($themes, $theme), '#{$key}');
      $theme-map: map-merge($theme-map, ($key: $value)) !global;
    }

    @if $theme == dark {
      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        @content;
      }
    } @else {
      @content;
    }

    $theme-map: null !global;
  }
}

@function themed($key) {
  @return map-get($theme-map, $key);
}
```

And finally a custom mixin and the class where I'm using it:

```
@mixin set-color-primary {
  @include themify($themes) {
    color: themed('primaryOne');
  }
}

.foo-container div {
  @include set-color-primary;
}
```

*Finally* this generates CSS like the following:

```
.foo-container div {
  color: #f0f;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .foo-container div {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

I was hoping I could squeeze out a few more lines and get something more like:

```
.foo-container div {
  color: #f0f;
  @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

Is this a limitation of my SASS knowledge or is this not possible in plain CSS?

Comment: No, this is not possible in plain CSS. You can not nest a media query inside of a css rule. You have to declare the media query first, then put the css rule inside of the media query block. The generated CSS is correct and cannot be condensed.

Comment: Perfect, thank you @K.G.